# listar elementos de diccionario y una lista en una linea

Tags: python, python-2.7, array, diccionarios

Hola estoy haciendo una prueba con listas y diccionarios, llegue a un punto en el que tenia algo asi.

```
datos = {'key1':'a','key2':'b','key3':'c'}
dic = ["alfa","beta","gama"]
```

Mi intención es imprimir

```
a,alfa
b,beta
c,gama
```

Lo intente con un ciclo 'for' pero por cada elemento del diccionario me imprime cuatro veces uno de la lista

```
for i in datos:
   t = datos[i]
   for l in dic:
      print t,l
```

Entre varias formas que he probado, una pista..

Comment: ellipsys, estás haciendo preguntas muy interesantes y bien planteadas. Recuerda que puedes aceptar una respuesta si alguien te responde y su publicación es útil para resolver tu problema. Más información en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Al hacer un bucle dentro de otro bucle repites la accion más veces de las que quieres.

Te recomiendo usar el comando [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) para iterar pares de diccionarios:

```
datos = {'key1':'a','key2':'b','key3':'c'}
dic = ["alfa","beta","gama"]

for i, j in zip(sorted(datos), dic):
    print (datos[i], j)
```

Comment: Hay que ordenar las claves de datos con `sorted` dentro de `zip` => `zip(sorted(datos), dic))`. Las claves de un diccionario no son recorridas como una secuencia ordenada por defecto, por lo tanto pueden aparecer en cualquier orden provocando un resultado no deseado en el ejercicio propuesto.

Comment: @CarlosUrda gracias tienes razon ahora lo ajusto, se me olvido ese comando